# Having two conditions in getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

In my application, under getDerivedStateFromProps, I have to write 2 conditions like this.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.errors) {
         return { errors: nextProps.errors };
      }

      if (nextProps.profile.profile) {
         const profile = nextProps.profile.profile;

         profile.company = !isEmpty(profile.company) ? profile.company : '';
         profile.website = !isEmpty(profile.website) ? profile.website : '';
         profile.location = !isEmpty(profile.location) ? profile.location : '';

         return {
            company: profile.company,
            website: profile.website,
            location: profile.location,
         };
      }

      return null;
   }
```

But, here only the first if condition works. How should I organize this code?

Comment: what i think is, only first if condition works because you have return statement in that condition.

Comment: What do you mean only the first condiition works? Sounds like you want them both to work at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
      const result = {};

      if (nextProps.errors) {
         result.errors = nextProps.errors;
      }

      if (nextProps.profile.profile) {
         const profile = nextProps.profile.profile;

         profile.company = !isEmpty(profile.company) ? profile.company : '';
         profile.website = !isEmpty(profile.website) ? profile.website : '';
         profile.location = !isEmpty(profile.location) ? profile.location : '';

         result.company = profile.company;
         result.website = profile.website;
         result.location = profile.location;
      }

      return result;
   }
```